# Postman and JAX RS for a post request

Tags: json, rest, jackson, postman, jax-rs

I´m trying to generate a **POST** request to my REST (JAX-RS) endpoint.
My issue is for the date:

I´m trying to insert LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime into my database.

Here is my DTO Class:

```
public class RequestDTO {

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private LocalDate startDate;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private LocalTime startTime;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private LocalDate endDate;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private LocalTime endTime;
```

I´m trying to post that via Postman zu my Endpoint:
[image]

But I got no error message in Postman and the Endpoint is never invoked (but the url is working). I´m getting only a 500 error.
So I guess the error is directly in Postman.

I would like to use the **ISO 8601** format.

My question would be:

1. Is the annotation correct in my DTO class?
2. Is the request correct in Postman (the date / time format etc.) ?

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Try to [use an ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42883319/2587435) to find the cause.

Comment: I have it already... But it´s not commited to my endpoint, but the Url is correct and it works fine if I´m not sending a date.... It seems there is something wrong in Postman request...There might be a validation directly in Postman?

Comment: What do you mean _"it´s not commited to my endpoint"_ . You mean it's not reporting the exception?

Comment: If I debug the endpoint, than is the endpoint not invoked.. Bit the url is 100% correct and is working Without date... the issue seems in the date in postman...

Comment: Have you set the property in the post I linked to?